# LinkedList writing to binary

Tags: c, binary, linked-list

Im trying to write to binary this linked list but it gives me an acess violation. The InsertVertice and InsertAresta create a new instance of that struct and are working fine so i dont know why this is giving me an error. If you need i can add the InsertVertice and InsertAresta functions here.

```
typedef struct Arestas
{
    int vertice;
    char Action[100];
    struct Arestas* next;
}*arestas;

typedef struct Vertices
{
    int vertice;
    struct Vertices* next;
    struct Arestas* adjacente;
}*vertice;

void WriteBin(vertice v)
{
    FILE * f;
    vertice apt = v;
    struct Arestas* aresta;
    int i;
    f = fopen("Grafo.bin","wb");
    while(apt!=NULL)
    {
        aresta = apt->adjacente;
        fwrite(apt->vertice,sizeof(int),1,f);
        while(aresta!=NULL)
        {
            fwrite(aresta->vertice,sizeof(int),1,f);
            fwrite(aresta->Acao,sizeof(char),100,f);
            aresta = aresta->next;
        }
        apt = apt->next;
    }
}

void main()
{
    vertice v= NULL;
    v = InsertVertice(v,1);
    v = InsertAresta(v,1,2,"ola");
    v = InsertAresta(v,1,3,"hey");
    v = InsertAresta(v,1,4,"oi");
    v = InsertAresta(v,1,5,"hello");
    WriteBin(v);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: *where* does it give you an access violation?

Comment: At the first and second fwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fwrite takes a pointer to the data you're writing as the first parameter. You're not passing it a pointer to an int. You're actually passing the int.

You probably need to do something like &(apt->vertice) for the first parameter.